# What are the pros and cons of using TTL vs actively sending a request to invalidate a key to invalidate a key in a cache?

Tags: caching, design-patterns, redis, architecture

Are there any best practices around key invalidation for caches like Redis? Should I let the key fall out after the TTL expires or should I call a delete on the key in question to remove that key from cache?

Would the actively calling a delete operation put more load and hurt the throughput of my cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are asking around how to handle memory management in Redis when using it as a cache. Redis implements some configurations `maxmemory` , `maxmemory-policy`, `maxmemory-samples`, `replica-ignore-maxmemory`, and `active-expire-effort`. For more [details](https://redis.io/topics/config) on these see the self documentation for your version.

Redis configs allow you to manage tradeoffs on CPU, memory and latency without needing to do external memory management. With that said `DEL` can be used to invalidate keys when your application is aware of state changes. And the TTLs set can be used with some of the memory management policies.